# The logistics around referring our users to other places

Tags: discussion

It's extremely rare, but I occasionally see people referring our users to other forums or mailing lists.

We have migrated a tiny number of questions to Engineering.SE but only when it became apparent that the question wouldn't get an answer at MMSE, and we've migrated a tiny number of questions to Statistics.SE (also known as CrossValidated) but only when the question seemed to be purely about statistics with no need for matter modeling knowledge (even this migration was done early in our site's lifetime and might not be handled the same if for example, someone at MMSE were to be able to answer the question quickly enough that it wouldn't harm MMSE much to have it around).

Apart from those migrations ***within*** the SE network to sites specializing in ***other*** topics, I occasionally see people referred to forums/mailing-lists ***outside*** the SE network for topics ***within*** matter modeling.

This totally goes against the original vision I had in mind when I proposed for SE to launch this site for us (first in 2018 unsuccessfully, then in 2019 successfully), which is for matter modelers ***not to have to sign up for >30 different forums,*** possibly requiring several different passwords (on possibly non-secure web servers maintained by scientific academics who aren't security experts).

I have never tried to convince the maintainers of those forums to shut down, or even to ask them to direct traffic to MMSE. I've even been hesitant to advertise MMSE on those forums/mailing-lists thus far. ***But*** I've also not recommended them much[*] either.

Perhaps the desire to persistently help grow the site is still stuck in me from my experience in Area51, Private Beta and the early days of Public Beta, and now we're at the stage where the site will likely do well and grow organically without us "going out of our way" as much; but I still think it's a disservice to our community to send people to forums in most cases. It is my belief that it will be better for the matter modeling community as a whole (not just MMSE but matter modelers in general) to slowly gravitate towards MMSE and away from forums which are only seen by small niche communities, on possibly insecure servers, with out-of-date versions of HTML, etc.

At the same time, I don't want to try to impose a "rule" that we can't recommend forums. I just wonder what the community thinks the logistics of such as recommendation should look like? If a question is unanswered for a few months, I don't mind recommending people to seek answers on forums. I've in fact created GitHub issues myself in the past, to help solve unanswered questions, and I've also recommended for people to ask in other places such as GitHub and the LAMMPS forum[*]. However, if people are directing users to a forum ***immediately*** without even giving the MMSE community a chance to answer, then ***not only might it be wasting the time of the question-asker by asking them to sign up at a different place and ask the same question twice,*** but it's also a bit unwelcoming and suggestive of their question not being welcome here and for them to go some place else. Plus it's not good for our growth, and in my opinion also not good for the MM community in general since it keeps people using archaic and spread out platforms rather than unifying all of us in one place.

Writing this entire post has made me a bit uncomfortable, and I've had this topic on my mind since the very early days of our Beta in 2020, because... well I can't quite explain it, but it doesn't feel good to tell people not to go elsewhere (a bit like Gaussian telling people not to compare the performance of their software to any other electronic structure software, or early forums about Mathematica discouraging people from talking about Maple when they said "[THIS IS NOT A PLACE TO DISCUSS ANY OTHER MATHEMATICS SOFTWARE. WE DO NOT CARE ABOUT OTHER SYSTEMS OR WHAT THEY CAN DO. STICK TO MATHEMATICA ONLY QUESTIONS" and "I WILL NOT POST COMPARISONS OF MATHEMATICA AND OTHER SYSTEMS"](https://web.archive.org/web/20070205092347/smc.vnet.net/mathgroup.html)). However, I do think it's the right thing to do.

Anyone is free to do what they want, but when someone comes to MMSE to ask a question, I personally will strive to welcome them and not send them away to other places, ***unless*** I see that our community is really struggling to answer the question. I usually bump up questions after about 6 months, ask for feedback from the OP, and even start contacting people in my network, or authors of related papers (even if I don't know them) to try to help MMSE questions get answered, and if all that fails, if someone wants to recommend a different forum it would seem fair. I'm not asking this community to go out of their way to discourage people from recommending other forums, or to encourage people not to do that, but I'm writing this in case it stimulates thought (and maybe discussion of people's opinions) on the matter.

[Here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9570/how-to-obtain-fingerprint-bits-as-smarts-pattern-in-rdkit#comment19963_9570)'s an example. [Here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8673/running-uspex-with-qe-in-cluster#comment17983_8673)'s another one.

Comment: Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9938/how-to-obtain-the-primitive-unit-cell-from-the-new-materials-project-website/10976#comment23790_9938